# Intersection of two arrays of Strings in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, intersection

This question might be a bit similar to this question but it is not.
[Intersection of two arrays of ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683939/intersection-of-two-arrays-of-ranges)

Okay, I am currently working on a project with VBA and I need to filter a table.
There are two filters looks like this (a1 and a2 contain strings for filter):

```
Dim a1() As String
Dim a2() As String

.Autofilter Field:=1, Criterial:=Array(a1)
.Autofilter Field:=1, Criterial:=Array(a2)
```

So as you notice, the 2nd line of autofilter just overwrites, in a way, the previous filter and this is not the way I would like the filter to behave. I would like to have an array to have mutual elements of a1 and a2 so that I can filter with the mutual elements of two arrays.

How would you intersect two arrays that contain couple of strings? I prefer not to use cells for this purpose just to reduce the worksheets on my workbook.

Comment: "Just do it". What prevents you from doing it? Find an algorithm, implement it, done.

Comment: Alternatively you can duplicate column and filter 1st column by `a1` and 2nd column by `a2`. EDIT: What are arrays' bounds? Are they equal to each other? How do you populate arrays? From `.Range.Value` or with `Split()` or manualy?

Answer (score 2):

#### Using dictionary:

```
Dim strDict As Object, i As Integer
Dim a1() As String, a2() As String
Dim strFilter As String
' ...
'Creating a dictionary
Set strDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
'I assumed both of the arrays start either from 1 or 0
'Populate dictionary with elements of one of the arrays
'Then check if elements from another array exist in dictionary
'And add them to a string
For i = Lbound(a2) To Ubound(a2)
    strDict(a2(i)) = a2(i)
Next
For i = Lbound(a1) To Ubound(a1)
    If strDict.Exists(a1(i)) Then strFilter = a1(i) & "," & strFilter
Next
'...
.Autofilter Field:=1, _
            Criterial:=Split(Left(strFilter, Len(strFilter) - 1), ","), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Using dictionary save us from using nested loops, number of iterations will be `Ubound(a1)`+`Ubound(a2)` instead of `Ubound(a1)`*`Ubound(a2)`, which is great, unless arrays are relatively small (<=2).

Answer (score 0):

You could run nested loops - the outer loop goes through one array, and the inner loop checks if the entry exists in the other array.  You can either output to a 3rd array, or use ReDim to expand the first array and add items to the end

```
Dim aIntersect() As String
Dim iLoop1 As Integer, iLoop2 As Integer
Dim bTest As Boolean
Dim iOutput As Integer

'Copy everything from a1 to aIntersect
iOutput = LBound(aIntersect)
For iLoop1 = LBound(a1) To UBound(a1)
    aIntersect(iOutput) = a1(iLoop1)
    iOutput = iOutput + 1
Next iLoop1
'Add the missing items from a2
For iLoop2 = LBound(a2) To UBound(a2)
    bTest = True ' Reset test
    For iLoop1 = LBound(a1) To UBound(a1)
        If a1(iLoop1) = a2(iLoop2) Then
            bTest = False 'Already exists
            Exit For 'No need to test further
        End If
    Next iLoop1
    If bTest Then 'If it did not exists, insert it
        aIntersect(iOutput) = a2(iLoop1)
        iOutput = iOutput + 1
    End If
Next iLoop1
'aIntersect now contains everything from a1, and anything from a2 that was not already in a1
```